# How can I download my code from heroku using GitHub method

Tags: github, heroku, github-actions, git-clone

I deployed my heroku app using the GitHub method. Heroku allows you to clone your code by using heroku git method. If you don’t use heroku git method than you would clone a empty file. How do I clone using the GitHub method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku does not proxy any non-`git push` deployments to its underlying repository](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> You **cannot** clone your app’s source from Heroku if you deploy your app with any method besides `git push`. Other deployment methods do not update your app’s Heroku Git repo, causing `heroku git:clone` to return an empty repository.

Since you've deployed by pushing to GitHub, simply clone from GitHub.